# Why do I get 'relative jump out of range' error whenever I add code

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tic-tac-toe

I've been having and solving this problem for a couple of times now, but I still don't know how I solved it. It's the third time I got this particular error and I can't fix it.

The code is pretty long (but repetitive) so I'll just cut it to the important parts

This is the part where I change and get errors

```
call putx

fou:
  cmp al,'4'
  jE  fou1
  jNE fiv

  fou1:

    mov ah, 02
    ;mov ch, 8
    mov dh, 8
    ;mov cl, 30
    mov dl, 30
    int 10h

    call putx

    fiv:
      cmp al,'5'
      jE  fiv1
      jNE six

      fiv1:
         mov ah, 02
         mov dh, 8
         mov dl, 34
         int 10h

         call putx

         six:
           mov ah,'3'
```

Whenever I add code to 'six:' I get the error here on 140 saying 'Relative Jump out of range by 0002h bytes

```
Stosb                   ;Else no put the byte in the buffer
cmp bl,32h
Je pl1
Jne wla
  pl1:
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,p1
Stosb                   ;Else no put the byte in the buffer
cmp bl,32h
Je pl1
Jne wla ;this is line 140
  pl1:
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,p1
```

What does this mean? What does 0002 bytes mean? I don't know why I get this error. I solved it earlier but I'm not sure how.

Here is the full code if it is needed. Bear with me, it is long (i do not know where the error may be so I'll put it as a whole)

```
.model small
.code
org 100h

start:


start: jmp main
lin db "|===|===|===|$"
r1 db "| 1 | 2 | 3 |$"
r2 db "| 4 | 5 | 6 |$"
r3 db"| 7 | 8 | 9 |$"
spa db 0ah,0dh,24h

p1 db"Player 1's Turn (X) : $"
p2 db"Player 2's Turn (O) : $"


main:

;start of the crap
mov ah, 02
mov ch, 5
mov dh, 5
mov cl, 28
mov dl, 28
int 10h

call line
call down
call row1

mov ah,09
lea dx,r1
int 21h

call down
;le end



;start of the crap
mov ah, 02
mov ch, 7
mov dh, 7
mov cl, 28
mov dl, 28
int 10h

call line
call down
call row2

mov ah,09
lea dx,r2
int 21h

call down
;le end




;start of the crap
mov ah, 02
mov ch, 9
mov dh, 9
mov cl, 28
mov dl, 28
int 10h

call line
call down
call row3

mov ah,09
lea dx,r3
int 21h

call down
;le end

mov ah, 02
mov ch, 11
mov dh, 11
mov cl, 28
mov dl, 28
int 10h

call line
call down





;input goes here
mov ah, 02
mov ch, 20
mov dh, 20
mov cl, 10
mov dl, 10
int 10h

mov ah,09
lea dx,p1
int 21h

mov ah,02
mov dl,al
int 21h

call down



;mov cx,2 
;again:
          CLD                     ;Incrementing direction
  mov bl,30h
  Get_another_byte:

    add bl,1h
    call down
    mov ah,02
    mov dl,bl
    int 21h                ;show the bl

    Mov AH, 7               ;Ms.Dos code to get one char
    Int 21h                 ;Ms.Dos does that for us and puts it in AL

    Cmp AL, 20h             ;Did he hit the return key ?
    Je  exi          ;Yes, now we can go on

    Stosb                   ;Else no put the byte in the buffer
    cmp bl,32h
    Je pl1
    Jne wla
      pl1:
        mov ah,09
        lea dx,p1
        int 21h

        mov ah,02
        mov dl,al
        int 21h

          ;code ni player 1

cmp al,'1'
jE  one
jNE two

one:

mov ah, 02
mov ch, 6
mov dh, 6
mov cl, 30
mov dl, 30
int 10h


call putx

two:

  cmp al,'2'
  jE  two1
  jNE thr

  two1:

  mov ah, 02
  mov ch, 6
  mov dh, 6
  mov cl, 34
  mov dl, 34
  int 10h

  call putx


  thr:

    cmp al,'3'
    jE  thr1
    jNE fou

    thr1:

    mov ah, 02
    mov ch, 6
    mov dh, 6
    mov cl, 38
    mov dl, 38
    int 10h

    call putx

    fou:
      cmp al,'4'
      jE  fou1
      jNE fiv

      fou1:

        mov ah, 02
        ;mov ch, 8
        mov dh, 8
        ;mov cl, 30
        mov dl, 30
        int 10h

        call putx

        fiv:
          cmp al,'5'
          jE  fiv1
          jNE six

          fiv1:
             mov ah, 02
             mov dh, 8
             mov dl, 34
             int 10h

             call putx

             six:
               mov ah,'3'


  taps:
    mov bl,30h
    jmp Get_another_byte

  exi:
    jmp exit
          ;end of code player1

        ;mov bl,30h
        sub bl, 2h   ;babalik niya yung 32 sa 1 (32-2 = 31)
        call down
        Jmp Get_another_byte
    wla:
        mov ah,09
        lea dx,p2
        int 21h

        mov ah,02
        mov dl,al
        int 21h

        ;mov bl,30h
        call down
        Jmp Get_another_byte    ;He's not done, so keep on

;loop again


row1 proc
  mov ah, 02
  mov ch, 6
  mov dh, 6
  mov cl, 28
  mov dl, 28
  int 10h
  ret
row1 endp


row2 proc
  mov ah, 02
  mov ch, 8
  mov dh, 8
  mov cl, 28
  mov dl, 28
  int 10h
  ret
row2 endp


row3 proc
  mov ah, 02
  mov ch, 10
  mov dh, 10
  mov cl, 28
  mov dl, 28
  int 10h
  ret
row3 endp




line proc
  mov ah, 09
  lea dx, lin
  int 21h
  ret
line endp

down proc
  mov ah, 09
  lea dx, spa
  int 21h
  ret
down endp



putx proc
  mov ah,02
  mov dl,"X"
  int 21h
  ret
putx endp


  exit:

int 20h
end start
```

Comment: You forgot to tell your assembler you have a cpu that supports 16 bit jumps and your code exceeds the default 8 bit distances. Either specify cpu or rewrite your code such that it doesn't need long conditional jumps. The usual trick is to reverse condition and use a longer range unconditional `jmp`. In fact your code is already set up for this, a `jne` after a `je` can be just a `jmp`...

Comment: I didn't think that it was that kind of problem. Thanks for answering. How do you specify cpu? If ever I can''t rewrite the code with shorter conditions

Comment: look at the encoding for the instruction, relative jumps will have a pc relative offset in the encoding.  there are only so many bits for each encoding, some can only reach say 127 bytes forward if you ask it to go 129 then you are 2 bytes further than it can go...

Comment: and there may be more than one encoding but you need to know what your specific assembler requires to get the other encoding (if that is the issue) remove the added lines, assemble then disassemble, examine the encoding (when successful but on the margin) and that should tell you what is going on...it gets even more fun because if you make that instruction longer it might be that you have yet another near pc relative instruction that you now pushed over the limit...

Comment: You didn't specify the assembler, looks like `masm`. Try putting `.386` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The relative jump uses a byte as an offset, so it can only jump 127 bytes forward and 128 bytes backward.
If you want to jump more bytes forward or backward you need to specify a CPU that supports that, the original 8086 does not.

If you're using MASM put `.386` at the top of the file, this will enable specific extensions introduced after the 8086. One of these extensions is 16-bit relative jump offsets, more than enough for your purpose.

If you're using another assembler google: `assembler directives [assembler name] cpu`.
This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot